# Set default location of opening window

Tags: compiz, window, panel, mate

I have ubuntuMATE 16.04 and I am using Compiz as desktop manager. Whenever I open a new app it starts at position 0,0 (Top Left Corner of the screen.)

It also overlaps the top panel.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the CompizConfig Settings Manager.

Go to Window Management > Place Windows, enable it, and in "Placement Mode" choose Centered.